# How to update API level in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, ide

Currently while executing the program it shows "current API level is 32 please update the API level to 33". How should I resolve this???

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6fa2.png)
I tried executing my code in android studio, but it says to update the API level. How to fix it?

Comment: You can change the compileSdkVersion on build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

You can go to file -> project structure -> you click your modules and change the "Compile Sdk Version" property to be 33.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).